# loop for fetching and or manipulating phylogenies in R over multiple values of another variable

Tags: r

I have a dataset in which there are multiple species listed for each value of another column (call it the index column) in R. I need to extract or prune a phylogeny (from phylomatic) for each column value, and then calculate the phylogenetic distance for each value of the index column. There are many index values in my dataset, so it is impractical to do this manually.

Example input data ( 2 columns, one for index and one for species):

```
Index      Species
A ;         Sp. 1
A ;         Sp. 2
A ;         Sp. 3
A ;         Sp. 4
B ;         Sp. 5
B ;         Sp. 1
C ;         Sp. 6
D ;         Sp. 7
D ;         Sp. 2
D ;         Sp. 8
D ;         Sp. 9
```

What I want for output (values made up; each index appears once and the phylogenetic distance of all its associated species is calculated):

```
Index;      phylogentic distance
A ;         7
B ;         3
C ;         1
D ;         5
```

I have downloaded a global tree (for all species in the dataset) from phylomatic using the brranching package. I could either set up a loop or function to prune the phylogeny to the species within each index category and calculate PD, or I could set up a function to extract a new tree from phylomatic for each value of the index, and then calculate PD. I would really appreciate if anyone has done something similar or has ideas about how to implement this in R. Much appreciated in advance!

```
library(brranching)

phylomatic(data$Species)
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. First I converted the Index column to numeric, and then I ran the following loop. The drop.tip() function is from the ape package.

```
IDs <- unique(d.test$index.num)

dd <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=length(IDs), ncol=2))

for (i in 1:length(IDs)) {
temp <- subset(d.test, d.test$index.num == i)
species <- as.vector(temp$Species)
species <- tolower(species)
pruned.tree <- drop.tip(tree, setdiff(tree$tip.label, species))
pd <- sum(pruned.tree$edge.length)
dd[i,1] <-i
dd[i,2] <- pd
}
```